# What would be the eta quotient for the Weierstrass equation $x^2 = y^2$?

Tags: totient-function, elliptic-equations, langlands-program

I am trying to find an as simple as possible example of a Weierstrass equation where the eta quotient exists and is not completely trivial.

> What would be the eta quotient for the Weierstrass equation $x^2 = y^2$ ?

At $n$ equal to a squarefree number it should be equal to https://oeis.org/A366562
or the conjectured form:

a(n) = [Mod[n, 2] = 1]A000010(n)*(-1)^A001221(n).

Comment: Related other example of Weierstrass equation : https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/11/a/3 and its Eta quotient: https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/Q/holomorphic/11/2/a/a/